# PyQt application: Restore the original look & feel after changing some QSS elements

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I'm changing the look of some elements in my pyQt application using a QSS style sheet. This has the effect of overriding many other properties of those elements as well (as noted in the documentation and many tutorials).

Now, I would like to restore these overridden properties, but I haven't managed to find the "original" style sheets on my system where the default themes are defined. Using the information from these style sheets I could restore the rest of the original look.

Could somebody give me hint where to find these style sheets? Or is there a more elegant way to achieve my goals?

Comment: There is no such stylesheet. The original styling is provided by style plugins: see [Styles and Style Aware Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html). (NB: the `QProxyStyle` class is only available in PyQt5).

Comment: That explains why searching for *.qss and *.css on my harddisk didn't help ...

Does that mean it is essentially not such a good idea to set css / qss properties of individual widgets or classes because it messes with the style system of Qt? 

@ekhumoro: I would accept your comment as an answer, it seems there is no simple solution I had hoped for.

Comment: In a nutshell: it depends (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default stylesheets. All the default styling is done by [style plugins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html).

When a stylesheet is set, it creates an instance of `QStyleSheetStyle` (which is a subclass of `QWindowsStyle`) and passes it a reference to the current style. The `QStyleSheetStyle` will try to apply the QSS rules *on top of* the current style, but where this is not possible, it will fall back to the `QWindowsStyle`.

And this is where the problems start, because there is no simple way to determine what a particular QSS rule will do. Sometimes it will have a very precise effect, and other times it will completely clobber the normal styling. In addition, the exact outcome depends on what the current style is. So a QSS rule might look good on your own system, but there's no guarantee it will do so on others.

Using stylesheets is therefore always a compromise. Creating a custom `QStyle` would give you much more control, but stylesheets will usually be much easier to write and maintain. So it's a trade-off between convenience and precision.

However, there is a third option available. Do nothing. Respect the user's choice of widget styling - or at the very least, don't force them to accept yours.

Comment: You got a point with the third option. Some styles I set do have a function (like highlighting an invalid entry etc.) but others really are forcing my taste upon the user. I'll take a look at the style plugin system though.