# How do I gray-out a label without disabling it?

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I have a few labels I want to sometimes look grayed-out, depending on some variable. Some of those labels have effects (such as changing those factors) when clicked. I'd like my program to look good regardless of what theme the user is using, so I can't hardcode the colors. How can I do this?

I can think of several solutions, but all of them have some annoying drawbacks:

- **Change the text color:** Sounds like the easiest solution, but it's a bit harder since I want to support theming/palettes. Especially if the system theme is changed while the program is running, since then I'd have to update the palette again.
- **Call `setDisabled()` and override `event`:** That just feels *wrong*, and also risks overriding platform behavior.
- **Make a custom text widget:** Would be possible, of course, but it would require either a *lot* of code duplication and wasted time, or be a rather half-assed and limited implementation.
- **Wrap `paintEvent` with a pair of `setDisabled()` calls:** No. Just no. Also, I don't know if that would work with concurrency.

Comment: Maybe play with `QWidget.setPalette()`?

Comment: From what I've seen, neither of those works particularly well with changing themes.

Comment: Despite [it's limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295877/984421), manipulating the palette is probably the best approach. If you use [color roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum), the palette will track the current theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the style sheet of this label, since it's a Widget. It works for me and when themes are changed because of OS switching or whatever, it keeps the same.

```
label.setStyleSheet("color: gray")
```

The style sheet have a CSS syntax. You can make wonderful things with it, just have a look on the [reference properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) and some [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider) for some distinct widgets.

Comment: "When themes are changed, it keeps the same" That's exactly what I *don't* want. I want it to use the theme's grayed-out (disabled) color.

Comment: What I mean is that it will keep only the letters gray and if you wants also borders and whatever, it won't change the  "layout" and how the buttons appears to be as a whole. Ain't that what you wanted? If you change the theme the appearance of it will change too, but not the minutiae that u set in the stylesheet.

Comment: If you didn't have a try I'd tell u to check it out and see if it works fine. But if you already told and tried, and it doesn't work for what you want then I think the best solution is the one of the guy bellow me.  ")

Answer (score 0):

Copy the brushes from the "Disabled" palette role to the "Active" role:

```
palette = mylabel.palette()
palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled)
palette.setColorGroup(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, palette.windowText(),
    palette.button(), palette.light(), palette.dark(), palette.mid(),
    palette.text(), palette.brightText(), palette.base(), palette.window())
mylabel.setPalette(palette)
```

`mylabel` should now look like it's disabled, but it's actually not.

This should work for any widget, not just labels.